# Close Chrome with extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

Is it possible to close the entire application within a chrome extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use the [Chrome Windows API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html) to close all windows:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({}, function(windows){
  for(var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++)
    chrome.windows.remove(windows[i].id);
});
```

To just close a tab, use [`chrome.tabs.remove()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove).

Comment: Surely this continues to leave the application running, just with no windows (I don't know whether on some OSs that results in the application exiting, but it certainly doesn't on OS X...)?